# GCP Cloud Data transfer - any notifications?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-data-transfer

I want to build a small solution that will transfer files from Azure to GCP. The solution itself works fine, but I don't see any solution anywhere that could inform me that the transfer started, ended or there was an error (e.g. on Slack). I can't see anything in the logs that could help me. I tried to do it with PUB/SUB but without any luck.

Is there any easy way to connect Data Transfer with slack or e-mail?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point in time, the Cloud Data transfer service has no way to send notifications(mail/slack/etc), you could try to implement something by monitoring the logs of the GCS bucket.

In the case you are mentioning, you could be [monitoring the logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/alerting/monitoring-logs#mgmt) of GCS looking for writes, and send a notification based on that, nevertheless, it would take some fine tuning on your side.

I would also recommend to create a feature request [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) so that Google knows that this feature is needed and they themselves implement it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I am part of Storage Transfer Service team. We offer a to get notified via pubsub of the state of the transfer job. It's an API only feature at this time. Check out [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/pub-sub-transfer).